# Function , class and variable all with the same name

Tags: c++, name-lookup

Why do some of these compile and some not compile?

Scenario 1: compilation error `'main' : redefinition; previous definition was 'data variable'`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main;
int main(){ }
```

Scenario 2: compilation error `syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'obj`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class main { };
int main(){ 
   main obj;
}
```

Scenario 3: working fine

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class main { };
int main(){ 
   class main obj;
}
```

Scenario 4 : working fine

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class main {};
main obj;
int main(){ }
```

Comment: How are those error messages not answering your question?

Comment: Urgh, looks like you've stumbled upon the old "namespace" feature from C, which has made it into C++ solely for compatibility reasons..

Comment: Your code doesn't "output" anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Name lookup works in terms of *names*.  The name is looked up, independent of what that name designates.

It's not permitted for the same name to be declared as both a function and a variable, in the same scope.

However, it is permitted for `class X` to exist even if `X` is the name of a function or a variable.   When you have `class X`, then the current scope gets `X` as a name (designating that class). If the same scope has `X` declared as both a typename and a variable name, then just looking up `x` finds the variable name.

If a new scope declares `X` then any use of `X` in that scope finds the name declared in its scope, this is called *shadowing*.  (Name lookup searches the current scope, then the scope which enclosed that, and so on up to the global scope).

1. Error, attempts to declare `main` as both a function and a variable
2. To process `main obj;`, the name `main` is looked up. The current scope is checked first, and it finds the function name `main`; so it does not check the global scope. We say that the inner scope's name *shadows* the outer scope's name. So, it is the same error as you would get from `void foo(); foo obj;`
3. `class main` unambiguously says to look up the class name `main`; that does not find `int main()` so it falls back to checking the global scope.
4. nothing new, `main obj;` makes no difference .

Another interesting example would be:

```
int x;
class x { };

int main()
{
    x = 1;        // ok
    x y;          // error, `x` means the int
    class x y;    // ok
}
```